# Save huge numpy in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix

I have to save numpy.zeros((61, 33, 2, 7)) this matrix in txt file and also I have to read again. I looking for some solving. but could not solve the problem.

Comment: Why must this be a text file? What format do you expect exactly?

Comment: Can you not save it as a `.npy`?

Comment: I need to save this data and print it back into a matrix and use it. .txt not required.

Comment: Reshape it to 2d, and use `savetxt` and `genfromtxt`.  Resahape again.  There's no standard for 3 or 4d array text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say you don't need to save it as a `.txt` file, you can save it to a `.npy` like so:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.zeros((61, 33, 2, 7))
np.save('/path/to/some/directory/some_file.npy', arr)
```